# JSON GET request prepending site URL to request URL

Tags: javascript, json, get

I have a pretty standard GET request written in JavaScript (just filled in an example URL below:

```
 this.getVideo= function(){

        var json = 'https://www.example.com';
        var getVideo = {
             url: json,
             type: 'GET',
             crossDomain: true,
             dataType: 'json',
             context : this,
             cache : true,
             timeout: 60000,
             success : function(e) {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(e);

                 var results = JSON.stringify(e);
                this.openPlayer(results);

             }.bind(this).
         };
         utils.ajaxWithRetry(getVideo);
    }.bind(this);
```

However, this fails because the GET request that's actually made is my site's URL prepended to the URL specified in my GET request (ie wwww.my-site.com/videos/www.example.com). I cannot figure out how or why this would be happening! I console log my url at multiple steps, and it's correct each time--why would the URL of the GET request change???

Comment: Add `http://` in front of the path.

Comment: Sorry, I do actually have http:// in my code. I've updated my question above.

Comment: I don't think it's related, but what is this code at the end of your success callback about? `.bind(this).`. Note that it ends with a period. I don't think any of that is necessary.

Comment: I bet the answer lies in the `utils.ajaxWithRetry(getVideo);`, which isn't shown here. What's happening there?

Comment: That's some error handling code.

Comment: It's got to be more than error handling. Something not shown here is performing the problematic ajax call.

Comment: Yeah, interesting. When I try to console log something in that function, it doesn't hit...